# How to prevent Vercel from deploying master branch if only README.md is changed?

Tags: git, github, next.js, vercel

I know it is possible to stop building deployments completely with Ignored Build Step on Vercel but I want to know how to push updates to non-critical files like a README without having it redeploy the entire project. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Vercel has added some docs that address [this exact situation](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-do-i-use-the-ignored-build-step-field-on-vercel#with-folders-and-workspaces:):

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD --quiet ./path/
```

If changes were committed to ./path/, the command will yield a non-empty response, allowing the build to proceed.

Try this out for a particular file.

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD --quiet README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Go to your project dashboard in Vercel. Go to Settings.

And add `git diff --quiet HEAD^ HEAD ./ ':(exclude)README.md'`

[image: Vercel Dashboard]